# 1991 Pontiac Grand Prix 3.1 Liter - Alternator replacement fail

Tags: alternator, pontiac, grand-prix

1991 Pontiac Gran Prix SE 3.1 liter 6 cylinder.

Alternator positive red wire from starter grounded out and split apart. What happened and why?

How do I fix it?

Is it safe to drive again?

Comment: This question is unclear. Could you please add some more information?

Comment: Can you add more information to your question please.  You can hit the edit button below your question to clean up and clarify.  If you add as much verbiage you can to clarify you will increase your chances of someone assisting.  As of know, it's a little confusing.  Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Comment: Picture would help.

Comment: Question is pretty clear IMO a alternator cable that's hooked directly to the battery shorted to ground. It didn't melt but "split" given the age of the vehicle and how common on cable fusible links were it's the first thing to think of.

Answer (score 1):

There's a 10ga fusible link on the cable from the alternator to starter. This needs to be replaced with a new cable or you can generally buy a new fusible link and crimp or solder it in place.

As to the why when a always hot cable shorts to ground it's basically a circuit with no load to limit the amount of amps. One of three things happen, a fuse blows if you're lucky or something in the circuit will melt or catch fire.

As long as the cable is properly repaired it's a non issue.